# Defining LIMIT by unique number of values

Tags: mysql, sql

Having following SQL query

```
SELECT service_id, service_box_id FROM table1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 10
```

which results into following table

```
service_id  | service_box_id 
12          | 1
12          | 2
12          | 3
21          | 1
21          | 2
33          | 1
33          | 2
33          | 3
33          | 4
33          | 5
```

So, query shows 10 rows, which, in this case, have 3 unique service_id values - 12, 21, 33.

Is it possible to define "LIMIT" in query to show **10 unique service_id values**, without running another sql query before it? Or any other method which limits output of query.

Desired output:

```
service_id  | service_box_id 
12          | 1
12          | 2
12          | 3
21          | 1
21          | 2
33          | 1
33          | 2
33          | 3
33          | 4
33          | 5
34          | 1
34          | 2
38          | 1
43          | 1
43          | 2
43          | 3
44          | 1
44          | 2
45          | 1
45          | 2
46          | 1
46          | 2
48          | 1
48          | 2
```

So, 10 unique service_id - 12, 21, 33, 34, 38, 43, 44, 45, 46, 48, but in total 24 rows.

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?  The answer is, it depends on what you want to see.

Comment: You could `GROUP BY service_id` in order to get unique services

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `Distinct` with `LIMIT` in where subquery.

```
SELECT service_id, service_box_id 
FROM table1
WHERE service_id in (
    SELECT service_id 
    FROM (
        SELECT Distinct service_id
        FROM table1 
        ORDER BY service_id 
        LIMIT 10
    ) t1
)

| service_id | service_box_id |
| ---------- | -------------- |
| 12         | 1              |
| 12         | 2              |
| 12         | 3              |
| 21         | 1              |
| 21         | 2              |
| 33         | 1              |
| 33         | 2              |
| 33         | 3              |
| 33         | 4              |
| 33         | 5              |
| 34         | 1              |
| 34         | 2              |
| 38         | 1              |
| 43         | 1              |
| 43         | 2              |
| 43         | 3              |
| 44         | 1              |
| 44         | 2              |
| 45         | 1              |
| 45         | 2              |
| 46         | 1              |
| 46         | 2              |
| 48         | 1              |
| 48         | 2              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vUhD4Bhj8UeNvqvstR4jQk/0)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, we can try using `DENSE_RANK` here

```
SELECT service_id, service_box_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY service_id) dr
    FROM table1
) t
WHERE dr <= 10;
```

If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, then we join to a subquery which finds the first 10 `service_id` values:

```
SELECT t1.service_id, t1.service_box_id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT service_id
    FROM table1
    ORDER BY service_id
    LIMIT 10
) t2
    ON t1.service_id = t2.service_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lowest service id values, then a simple method is:

```
SELECT service_id, service_box_id
FROM table1
WHERE service_id < (SELECT DISTINCT tt1.service_id
                    FROM table1 tt1
                    ORDER BY tt1.service_id
                    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
                   );
```